Updating Sitecore instance from Sitecore 10.2.1 pre release to 10.2.1 final update through Update Installation Wizard
Looking for updating Sitecore instance from Sitecore 10.2.1 pre-release to 10.2.1 final update through Update Installation Wizard. But couldn't find the Sitecore 10.2.1 rev. 009559 update package in the Sitecore developer portal or google anywhere. please let me know if anyone knows the URL to download the sc update package for Sitecore 10.2.1 rev. 009559(final update)?
Thanks in Advance

Please Check the Official Sitecore Downloads Page:
https://developers.sitecore.com/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/102/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_102
Hope this helps!!!

Couldn't find the update package here in this URL

Contact Sitecore Support! They might help you out.

This is the correct link to download Sitecore 10.2.1 (rev 009559):
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/102/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_102_Update1
I just tried downloading one of the packages and can confirm it is correct.
Update 17/06/24
I think you are mistaken. There is no such thing as an update package (this was the old approach). You need to update your solution to use the new 10.2.1 DLL via nuget. Then follow the update guide T the link above.
Update 19/06/24
The Sitecore Nuget packages (including 10.2.1) are available via this feed: https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
See screen shot below:

All the information you need to upgrade from Sitecore 10.2.x to 10.2.1 is in the Update Installation Guide. One of the first sections shows this info:

To update to Sitecore XP 10.2.X, you must be a local administrator on
SQL Server and follow this methodology:

Install the new version of Sitecore and any modules that you are using beside yourexisting Sitecore XP installation.
Connect the new installation to your databases.
Connect the new installation to your Solr indexes.
Import the client languages.
Deploy your solution on top of the new installation. • Perform the post-upgrade steps (optional).


Note that it says 'install new version beside existing'. This is the step that will provide the necessary config files (if any changed). You then deploy your newly updated solution (with 10.2.1 Nuget) over the top of the new sitecore.

Yes, this is the url where we can download  new instance setup(for XP, XM, etc.) files but not the update package for upgrading the sitecore instance.

Please see update

Either, I couldn't find the final update nuget package of Sitecore 10.2.1 rev. 009559.  So please let me know if you know the url?
Also, the final update of the sitecore version 10.2.1 might have config changes which can't be install install via nuget.

Please see update
